# MSSQL query select top by weighting

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please refer a table below. Each `Targeted_Product_Id` has 100 `Recommended_Product_Id`'s. I want to select **top 6** by `Weighting.` I was trying to achieve it using `HAVING` but unfortunately failed. Could you please help me construct such query?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH RemoveDuplicatesCTE AS
(
    SELECT   Targeted_Product_Id,
             Recommended_Product_Id,
             Weighting
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Targeted_Product_Id,Recommended_Product_Id ORDER BY Targeted_Product_Id,Recommended_Product_Id) AS rn
    FROM     Targeted_Product
)
,ProductsCTE AS
(
    SELECT   Targeted_Product_Id,
             Recommended_Product_Id,
             Weighting
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Targeted_Product_Id ORDER BY Weighting DESC) AS rn
    FROM     RemoveDuplicatesCTE
    WHERE    rn = 1
)
SELECT   Targeted_Product_Id,
         Recommended_Product_Id,
         Weighting
FROM     ProductsCTE 
WHERE    rn<=6
ORDER BY Targeted_Product_Id,
         rn DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for amazing query! Should I add `ORDER BY Weighting **DESC**` in order to select top weighted products?

Comment: @WildGoat Indeed, if you want the most weighted you should order by desc. I will update my post.

Comment: You probably want to add an ORDER BY at the very bottom as well. Otherwise you may see weird results like row numbers 4 and 5 appearing before rows 1 thru 3.

Comment: Also, in my data I've duplicates sometimes as `recommended_product_id`. Is there are any way I can filter them out so that mapping between `Targeted_Product_Id` and `Recommended_Product_id` would be at most 1?

Comment: How do you want ties to be handled? ROW_NUMBER will pick one at random unless you ensure that its ORDER BY clause is unique. If you want to return all ties, even if this means 7+ records, then use RANK instead. (There is also DENSE_RANK, but you don't want that for this use case.)

Comment: @WildGoat Sure, just use a GROUP BY subquery. You'll need to figure out how to handle Weighting, maybe MAX or AVERAGE.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos, thanks! but unfortunately duplicates still in the results.

Comment: I would like to see an example in SQL Fiddle please.